# Docker php 7.1 imagick

Tags: php, docker

Docker php 7.1 imagick:-

```
pecl install imagick \
&& docker-php-ext-enable imagick \
```

> - No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/imagick"
>     install failed
> - ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build

Comment: What is your question kind sir?

Comment: The excepted answer here worked for me: https://serverfault.com/questions/57377/installing-imagick-php-extension-on-ubuntu/57378

Answer (score 11):

From the official [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/) docs:

> "E: Package 'php-XXX' has no installation candidate"
>
> As of docker-library/php#542, this image blocks the installation of Debian's PHP packages. There is some additional discussion of this change in docker-library/php#551 (comment), but the gist is that installing Debian's PHP packages in this image leads to two conflicting installations of PHP in a single image, which is almost certainly not the intended outcome.
>
> For those broken by this change and looking for a workaround to apply in the meantime while a proper fix is developed, adding the following simple line to your Dockerfile should remove the block (with the strong caveat that this will allow the installation of a second installation of PHP, which is definitely not what you're looking for unless you really know what you're doing):
>
> RUN rm /etc/apt/preferences.d/no-debian-php
>
> The proper solution to this error is to either use FROM debian:XXX and install Debian's PHP packages directly, or to use docker-php-ext-install, pecl, and/or phpize to install the necessary additional extensions and utilities.

## The Solution

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.1

RUN apt update && \
    apt upgrade && \
    apt install -y libmagickwand-dev --no-install-recommends && \
    pecl install imagick && docker-php-ext-enable imagick && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Build it with:

```
$ sudo docker build -t exadra37/php-imagick:7.1 .

... some output ommitted ....

s/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/imagick.so

Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/imagick.so'
Installing '/usr/local/include/php/ext/imagick/php_imagick_shared.h'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/imagick-3.4.3
configuration option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location
You should add "extension=imagick.so" to php.ini
Removing intermediate container 71902c85c47a
 ---> 8142e9efd5ea
Successfully built 8142e9efd5ea
Successfully tagged exadra37/php-imagick:7.1
```

Checking it is installed:

```
$ sudo docker run --rm -it exadra37/php-imagick:7.1 bash
root@012656fef3a0:/# php -i | grep -ir imagick -
Additional .ini files parsed => /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-imagick.ini
imagick
imagick module => enabled
imagick module version => 3.4.3
imagick classes => Imagick, ImagickDraw, ImagickPixel, ImagickPixelIterator, ImagickKernel
Imagick compiled with ImageMagick version => ImageMagick 6.9.7-4 Q16 x86_64 20170114 http://www.imagemagick.org
Imagick using ImageMagick library version => ImageMagick 6.9.7-4 Q16 x86_64 20170114 http://www.imagemagick.org
imagick.locale_fix => 0 => 0
imagick.progress_monitor => 0 => 0
imagick.skip_version_check => 0 => 0
root@012656fef3a0:/#
```

Answer (score 7):

The answer from @Exadra37 is correct. But please note that you can also remove some APT packages after the installation of the PHP extension (they are needed only to compile/install the extension, not to use it - you'll save almost 200 MB):

```
FROM php:7.1

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y libmagickwand-dev && \
    pecl install imagick && \
    docker-php-ext-enable imagick && \
    apt-get remove --purge -y automake autotools-dev bzip2-doc fontconfig gir1.2-freedesktop gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 gir1.2-glib-2.0 gir1.2-rsvg-2.0 icu-devtools javascript-common libblkid-dev libbz2-dev libcairo-gobject2 libcairo-script-interpreter2 libcairo2 libcairo2-dev libcroco3 libdatrie1 libdjvulibre-dev libdjvulibre-text libdjvulibre21 libelf1 libexif-dev libexif-doc libexif12 libexpat1-dev libffi-dev libfontconfig1-dev libfreetype6-dev libfribidi0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-bin libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev libgirepository-1.0-1 libglib2.0-bin libglib2.0-data libglib2.0-dev libglib2.0-dev-bin libgraphite2-3 libharfbuzz0b libice-dev libice6 libicu-dev libilmbase-dev libilmbase23 libjbig-dev libjpeg-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libjs-jquery libjxr-tools libjxr0 liblcms2-dev liblqr-1-0-dev libltdl-dev liblzma-dev liblzo2-2 libmagickcore-6-arch-config libmagickcore-6-headers libmagickcore-6.q16-6-extra libmagickcore-6.q16-dev libmagickwand-6-headers libmagickwand-6.q16-dev libmagickwand-dev libmount-dev libmpdec2 libopenexr-dev libopenexr23 libopenjp2-7-dev libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libpangoft2-1.0-0 libpcre16-3 libpcre3-dev libpcre32-3 libpcrecpp0v5 libpixman-1-0 libpixman-1-dev libpng-dev libpng-tools libpthread-stubs0-dev libpython3-stdlib libpython3.7-minimal libpython3.7-stdlib libreadline7 librsvg2-2 librsvg2-common librsvg2-dev libselinux1-dev libsepol1-dev libsm-dev libsm6 libthai-data libthai0 libtiff-dev libtiffxx5 libtool libwmf-dev libwmf0.2-7 libx11-dev libxau-dev libxcb-render0 libxcb-render0-dev libxcb-shm0 libxcb-shm0-dev libxcb1-dev libxdmcp-dev libxext-dev libxml2-dev libxrender-dev libxrender1 libxt-dev libxt6 mime-support python3 python3-distutils python3-lib2to3 python3-minimal python3.7 python3.7-minimal readline-common shared-mime-info uuid-dev x11-common x11proto-core-dev x11proto-dev x11proto-xext-dev xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev zlib1g-dev && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Managing the list of required APT packages may be a mess, so I developer a script to do that.
You can simply write something like this:

```
FROM php:7.1

COPY --from=mlocati/php-extension-installer /usr/bin/install-php-extensions /usr/bin/

RUN install-php-extensions imagick
```

This `install-php-extensions` script supports the PHP extensions [listed here](https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer#supported-php-extensions)